# On reboot listeners don't start but restarting the service after will start them

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

when I reboot ubuntu the listener service comes up but it doesn't seem to have any listeners

```
lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 24-JUL-2014 15:34:43

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dex-ci.escalation-point.com)(PORT=1522)))
 STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                24-JUL-2014 15:33:58
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 44 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ip-10-113-43-249/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1522)))
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

after a `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe restart`

```
 lsnrctl status | sed -e 's/^/     /'

 LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 24-JUL-2014 15:42:15

 Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

 Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dex-ci.escalation-point.com)(PORT=1522)))
 STATUS of the LISTENER
 ------------------------
 Alias                     LISTENER
 Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
 Start Date                24-JUL-2014 15:41:24
 Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 50 sec
 Trace Level               off
 Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
 SNMP                      OFF
 Default Service           XE
 Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
 Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/dex-ci/listener/alert/log.xml
 Listening Endpoints Summary...
   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522)))
   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=8888))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
 Services Summary...
 Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
   Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
 Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
   Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
 The command completed successfully
```

What this tells me is that my configuration is fine, so it's something going on a boot, maybe a race condition... I have looked at the logs and was unable to find anything interesting. What kinds of things could cause these services to not come up on a restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the hostname not getting set consistently on boot, and was not correctly available at that time but was later.